# MySQL update 2 columns using IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update

I would like to update 2 columns within a table. The POST value is either 1 or 0.
So I have the below query, I not sure is it working but I am looking for better way to do this.

If the POST value ($yes_no) is equal to 1 then I need increase tableA.num_yes +1
and decrease tableA.num_yes -1.

So the same if POST value ($yes_no) is equal to 0.

```
t.num_yes = IF($yes_no = 1, t.num_yes + 1, t.num_yes),
t.num_no = IF($yes_no = 1, t.num_no - 1, t.num_no),
t.num_no = IF($yes_no = 0, t.num_no + 1, t.num_no),
t.num_yes = IF($yes_no = 0, t.num_yes - 1, t.num_yes)
```

Comment: Sorry do you want to do this in PHP? or SQL? You do know you can do the lot with one If statement?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I was doing this in SQL. But i'm not sure the perfomance.

Comment: Well JW gave you the SQL. I see little to add to it. However, if you are pulling data down from the DB just to change it, it's always better to do it in SQl, because then you don't have to pull it down and push it back again. There are situations where this isn't true, but in the main if you can do it in SQL you should.

Comment: Not to mention the server will beal with concurrent access and transaction isolation, whereas you've have to jump through a lot of hoops to do that in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use `CASE` on this problem. example,

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     num_yes = CASE  WHEN $yes_no = 1 
                        THEN num_yes + 1
                        ELSE num_yes - 1
                    END,
        num_no = CASE   WHEN $yes_no = 1 
                        THEN num_no - 1
                        ELSE num_no + 1
                    END
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21763/1)

Comment: So how the performance?  Which is better doing this in PHP or SQL?

Comment: if you were to ask me, I'd rather do it via query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UPDATE  tableName as t
SET 
        t.num_yes = IF($yes_no = 1,t.num_yes + 1,t.num_yes - 1),
    t.num_no = IF($yes_no = 1,t.num_yes - 1,t.num_yes + 1)
```